# Android Facebook connection

Tags: android, facebook

In one of the example apps from Facebook for Android, I have in one java file(Session), some variables, such as: TOKEN, EXPIRES, KEY, UID, NAME, APP_ID. At the Facebook Developers Webpage at My Apps, I have App ID, API Key and App Secret. Where i need to put App ID, where API Key and Where App Secret? 
(Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1):

To communicate with Facebook using your app, you need to create a new Facebook object passing in the App ID as the parameter for the constructor. You do not need to use the API key or App secret in your code for this purpose.

Comment: thanks... but whait is the TOKEN and EXPIRE_IN string variables?

Comment: these concepts are about Authentication, which you can read up more at : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: A token is a string that represents your authorized access code when you app has connected to FB. Each token expires after a certain time, which i think is what EXPIRE_IN represents.

Comment: If you feel that I've answered all your questions, could you please accept this answer as the solution (by clicking the green tick on the left)? Thanks.